# Report showing incorrect total

Tags: reporting, import, bulk-api

I have just imported a load of records using Bulk API

Bulk API log says - X
SOQL says - X
Report says - Y

Filtering is the same across the board.

Any ideas?

Thx

Comment: Can you post the report definition? It is likely a filter or permissions issue and seeing the definition would help us out.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does your report have "show my team's opportunities" or similar? Flip it to show all ;)
2. Is date range set to "all time"?
3. If it's Account or Opportunity report - check the Role / Territory hierarchy that it's saved with and make sure it's pointing to top Role?
4. Are you reporting on just 1 object or maybe parent and child? Could the total be from parents?
5. Have you accessed the report from dashboard or directly?
6. Report can be cut to display only 2K rows, check if you don't see on top "showing 2K out of...". Hit export details to really nail it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the end was this - some contacts were not getting probably linked to the Accounts. Hence why the total contacts in the backend was one number and the report another.

Thank you for responding.